# How to Incremental/Updated data in data transformation template

Tags: apache-nifi, kylo

would you please tell me the process to add the commit release high water mark in data transformation template by putting water mark value to high  as like we do in  data ingest . because i need to get the incremental/updated  data .

i got this solution by reading docs , but not able to get any idea how to do practically . Ultimately my requirement is to get the incremental and new data in data transformation .

If you have inputs for this please give me reply

Answer (score 0):

Your template needs to start with a LoadHighWaterMark processor. This is used to put the current high water mark value into a flow file attribute. The initial value is null until it is updated by a ReleaseHighWarkMark processor. The LoadHighWaterMark processor also prevents the feed from executing until the high water mark is released.

Then you need to have a ReleaseHighWaterMark processor connected to every failure relationship in your flow, and another ReleaseHighWaterMark processor connected to the final success relationship in your flow. It is important that every flow file ends at a ReleaseHighWaterMark processor because the LoadHighWaterMark processor blocks until the current flow file is released.

The Mode attribute on a ReleaseHighWaterMark processor indicates whether to save the new high water mark value or keep the existing value. The ReleaseHighWaterMark processor for the final success relationship should have Mode set to Commit so the new high water mark value is saved. The ReleaseHighWaterMark processor for all failure relationships should have Mode set to Reject so the existing high water mark value is retained.

Please see the Kylo documentation for more information: http://kylo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/how-to-guides/NiFiProcessorsDocs.html#high-water-mark-processors